# Cannot enter password to reset keychain

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm trying to reset my keychain (Yosemite 10.10.4).

- When I enter my wifi password I get "A keychain cannot be found to store my_wifi_sid"
- I click "Reset to Defaults"
- I get "Are you sure you want to reset your keychain? This will delete all your saved passwords, keys, and certificates. You cannot undo this operation" and click "Reset"
- I get "Please enter your login password. This password will be used to create your new keychain." with a password field.  Attempts to type in this field interact with whatever app is in the background (browser, desktop).  I can click the "Show password" checkbox.

This issue has also been reported at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6788761.  Upgrades did not help.

Deleting keychain folders via the command line ends up with the same result (not saving passwords and the above dialog).  This started about a month ago and does not appear to be associated with any system update.

Any tips on troubleshooting, logs to look at would be appreciated.

**Update**

tl;dr: disabling the Guest User and upgrading to El Capitan seems to have done the trick.

Not what I'd call an answer since I can't tell you which action is the fix, but here are two things,  one or both of which may have solved my problem.

I tried to log into the Guest User on this machine and learned that somehow I got a not-managed Guest User account.  This Guest User was asking for a password (which I did not know).  So I disabled the Guest User account.

Disabling the Guest User account seemed to solve this issue for some (but not all) of the users.  Next I downloaded the El Capitan installer to a thumb drive and installed it on my MacbookPro.  Now all of my keychain issues appear to be fixed.

Comment: What does the Wifi password has to do with keychain ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I am asked to re-enter my wifi password every time I log in.  So the fact that it is a wifi password may be inconsequential aside from the fact that this is something that Yosemite tries (unsuccessfully) to store in the keychain.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem.  Following the steps in [this article](http://www.mrgeek.me/apple/how-to-fix-the-wifi-bug-in-yosemite-using-keychain-reset/) helped me resolve my issue:

1. Open Keychain using Spotlight (⌘-<kbd>Space</kbd>)
2. Go to Keychain Access → Preferences
3. Click <kbd>Reset My Default Keychain</kbd>
4. Restart your Mac

Comment: Thank you @jack. That did not work for me though.

Comment: Links rot. Please include the relevant information behind in the link in your answer.